# Changing outside variables from a function

Tags: javascript, variables, cordova, ionic-framework

I use `cordova` and `ionic` for my mobile application.

I trying to use `$http.get()` for loading a `JSON` web service, so I wrote this code :

```
.controller('loading', function ($scope, $state, $http) {
        var loadedService = {
                news: false,
                users: false
            };

        $http.get('http://{url}/users')
            .success(function (result) {
                loadedService.users = result;
            });
```

I want to change the `loadedService.users` to returned `result` from webservice.

But when I trying to `console.log(loadedService.users)` I will get `false` (the default value for this variable).

What should I do?

Comment: define `var loadedService` outside of any method.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Thanks for comment, but I cannot understand your mean, I defined `loadedService` outside of `$http`

Answer (score 0):

$http.get, or javascript in general is asynchronous. Put console.log inside the success callback of http.get, you will see that (hopefully), you are getting correct results there. But if you put console.log after the get call, you will see the false output since your get call is still busy but your js keeps running. Long story short, js is asynchronous.